# Does Ubuntu Server have a Trash?

Tags: command-line, server, files, trash, rm

I'm using the server version of Ubuntu. I was wondering if files still go into the "trash" etc. with this version.
I'm been deleting stuff and I just want to make sure the stuff is not being put into the trash.

Answer (score 9):

No trash in the Server version. The `rm` command deletes it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. If i delete something using something like winscp it deletes it all the way as well then i take it?

Comment: Not sure killer. I don't use winscp. You should probably ask a new question though.

Comment: @kkiller23, yes, and you can't easily get around that. I suggest you simply set up a backup solution for the inevitable accidental delete.

Comment: Server vs desktop has nothing to do with it.  If you install the gui on server and delete files there, they go to the trash.  If you `rm` on desktop or server, they are deleted immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You do not say how you delete files.
There could be a "trash" if you use some text mode file manager, for example.

But let's assume you use the `rm` command in the shell:

Normally, `rm` should just delete files, without using a "trash". But for various reasons, like installing something accidentally, or using an example `.bashrc` without checking, it could be something else - it's easy to check, so you should: Use `command -v` to find out what command you're running with the name `rm`:

```
$ command -v rm
/usr/bin/rm
```

That looks good (1). Equally, `/bin/rm` would be good.

If `rm` is changed to use trash, it may look like this:

```
$ command -v rm       
alias rm=trash-put
```

or

```
$ command -v rm       
alias rm=gvfs-trash
```

Normally, this change is only applied when `rm` is used in an interactive shell.

Also, you may check whether `libtrash` is installed in some way. It changes how progams  work, including `rm`,  on library call level.

---

(1) Actually, `/usr/bin/rm` may be `safe-rm`, from a package of the same name:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/rm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb  1  2014 /usr/bin/rm -> safe-rm
```

*Answering a question from a comment:*
If `winscp` is an implementation of `scp`, then you can not delete files with it; You copy files to another machine, so you get more copies. You could use it to overwrite files, though - but that's not what you talk about.